# Sorting List of objects having list in it in java

Tags: sorting, arraylist

I have a class Person which has couple of variables. The class City has List of Person objects as its only variable. And the class State has List of city objects as its only variable.

From a test class i created a arraylist containing City objects. How do I sort the City objects in the list? i.e., how to sort an arraylist containing a type of objects, where each object has another list in it.

Person class

```
    public class Person {

        private String name;
        private Integer age;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public static Comparator<Person> personComparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
                int returnResult = o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
                if (returnResult == 0) {
                    return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
                }
                return returnResult;
            }
        };

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((age == null) ? 0 : age.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (!(obj instanceof Person))
                return false;
            Person other = (Person) obj;
            if (age == null) {
                if (other.age != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!age.equals(other.age))
                return false;
            if (name == null) {
                if (other.name != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
```

City class:

```
     public class City {
        private List<Person> personList;

        public List<Person> getPersonList() {
            if (personList == null) {
                personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
            }
            return personList;
        }

        public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
            this.personList = personList;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result
                    + ((personList == null) ? 0 : personList.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (!(obj instanceof City))
                return false;
            City other = (City) obj;
            if (personList == null) {
                if (other.personList != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!personList.equals(other.personList))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }
```

State class:

```
public class State {
    private List<City> cityList;

    public List<City> getCityList() {
        if (cityList == null) {
            cityList = new ArrayList<City>();
        }
        return cityList;
    }

    public void setCityList(List<City> cityList) {
        this.cityList = cityList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((cityList == null) ? 0 : cityList.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof State))
            return false;
        State other = (State) obj;
        if (cityList == null) {
            if (other.cityList != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!cityList.equals(other.cityList))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setName("John");
        p1.setAge(40);

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setName("Antony");
        p2.setAge(50);

        Person p3 = new Person();
        p3.setName("Bob");
        p3.setAge(24);

        Person p4 = new Person();
        p4.setName("Mark");
        p4.setAge(35);

        City city1 = new City();
        city1.getPersonList().add(p1);
        city1.getPersonList().add(p2);

        City city2 = new City();
        city2.getPersonList().add(p3);
        city2.getPersonList().add(p4);

        State state1 = new State();
        state1.getCityList().add(city1);
        state1.getCityList().add(city2);

        //How to sort the citylist in the state object?



    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to sort the List<City> based on? Number of people?

Comment: Basically i need to check whether two state object is equal. State object has List of Cities. So, i need to sort the City first to do arraylist.equals(anotherArrayList). The problem is, the arraylist.equals(anotherarraylist) is checking based on the order. So, i need to order(sort) the cities first within state objects.

Answer (score 0):

Develop a method called compareTo that compares some field within the city object to determine the order that you want, after you do that, you can call the method Collections.sort(); on the initialized array list object. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) find out more.

Comment: I thought of that, but if you see there is no field within City object other than the list of Person.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the Comparable interface. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is the documentation.